# How can I remove a scroll indicator from selected pages

Tags: css, indexing, scroll, squarespace

I've been working on a site using Squarespace, Miller template, but have not found any answer on the Squarespace foras. I found a code that supposedly should do what I am asking for – that is to remove the scroll indicator from the page I apply it on. The only problem is that it apparently removes the scroll indicator from all so called "index pages", even though the code is only injected into the page header of the index page I want the scroll arrow to be removed from.

The site is: https://.kallemoberg.com

I want to remove the arrow from the home page only (it is only barely visible there, but it's there, around his feet). I've used the following code which I got from this site: https://www.ghostplugins.com/steps/8ehn58jk

```css
<style>
.Index-page-scroll-indicator-text, .Index-page-scroll-indicator-arrow {
  display: none!important;
}
</style>
```

PS: When writing this post, the code above is not active. I'm a n00b, and have tried my best to look around for solutions, but now I've come to a dead end. Any help with this would be much appreciated!  -^-

Comment: the css code above should work. did you inject it in your squarespace page?

Comment: @MaZoli Is right, It should work. You better use this css `.Index-page-scroll-indicator { display: none !important; }`

Comment: @MaZoli – I injected it only in the page header of the index page I want it removed from from, yes. In my squarespace editor window, the scroll arrows disappear from that page, but are active in the other index page. Live on the world wide web, however, the arrows disappear from all index pages.

Comment: @antlis –  Thanks for the suggestion. That code snippet does not seem to work. Right onw I'm only running ".index-page-scroll-indicator-arrow" and not the ".index-page-scroll-indicator-text" portion of the initial code, but the result is the same – it removes the arrow from all pages, even though the code is only injected into the header of that specific page.

Comment: `#collection-5d9383c83bab2261f1c0a3a9 .Index-page-scroll-indicator-arrow {
  display: none!important;
}`

Try this code, it should remove arrow from homepage only. I think, I think thats unique id for the index page - 5d9383c83bab2261f1c0a3a9, it may change in the future if you going to do some manipulations with pages, like moving them from one place to another in the squarespace admin panel, I'm not familiar with squrespace.

Comment: @antlis – you're a gem. Seems like that did the trick. Thanks a lot!